# Selecting desired line from table by grouping fields

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

```
+------+-------+--------+
| Id   | code  |  title |
+------+-------+--------+
|  1   |  123  |        |
+------+-------+--------+
|  2   |  123  |   abc  |
+------+-------+--------+
|  3   |  456  |        |
+------+-------+--------+
|  4   |  678  |  bcd   |
+------+-------+--------+
|  5   |  678  |        |
+------+-------+--------+
|  6   |  8910 |        |
+------+-------+--------+
```

I have an sql table like this. What i would like to do is to select distinct `code` and query the results. Query should select the line with `title` primarily. If the title is empty, then should select the other line with the same `code`.

My desired output:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
|  2    | 123   |   abc  |
+-------+-------+--------+
|  3    | 456   |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
|  4    | 678   |   bcd  |
+-------+-------+--------+
|  6    | 8910  |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: What if both rows of 123 were not null in the title?

Comment: @forpas not possible in my condition

Comment: Is there a case there are more than 2 rows for a code? Also what do you mean by empty? Is it null or maybe an empty string?

Comment: @forpas yes possible. And i mean it's null.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by code order by (title is not null) desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Alternatively, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.code = t.code
              order by (t2.title is not null) desc
              limit 1
             );
```